# Jaxb annotation @xmlelement(name="ElementName") not binding with xml element name

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc, jaxb, unmarshalling

My Spring MVC Web Service code is as follows.

Model Class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="wrappedSecretData")
public class VendorData {


        private long lKeyId;



        @XmlElement(name="keyId")
        public long getlKeyId() {
            return lKeyId;
        }


        public void setlKeyId(long lKeyId) {
            this.lKeyId = lKeyId;
        }       
    }
```

Controller Method

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/vendor", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String addVendor(@RequestBody VendorData vendorData) {

            /*Checking recieved value*/
            System.out.println(vendorData.getlKeyId());//**Returning 0 value **
            return "Success";
        }
```

Xml request body for web service

```
<wrappedVendorSecretsMetadata>
    <keyId>1</keyId>
</wrappedVendorSecretsMetadata>
```

I am getting "0" value in lKeyId(Bold comment).
Where am I doing wrong.
Please provide the correct way to bind the xml element to object member using @XmlElement(name="keyId") annotation.

Comment: Unmarshalling your example XML with your `VendorData` class works fine for me (including `lKeyId = 1`). So, probably the problem is in the Java code part which you didn't show.

Comment: I have added complete code of my web service.Please help me where am I doing wrong.I am getting problem in Unmarshalling it.How do I Unmarshall it?

Comment: `wrappedSecretData` != `wrappedVendorSecretsMetadata`

Answer (score -1):

I think you need the @XmlElement only over the variable declaration.

Comment: I used @XmlElement over variable declaration but still not working.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="wrappedVendorSecretsMetadata")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class VendorData {

    private long lKeyId;

    public VendorData(){

    }

    @XmlElement(name="keyId")
    public long getlKeyId() {
        return lKeyId;
    }

    public void setlKeyId(long lKeyId) {
        this.lKeyId = lKeyId;
    }       
}
```

Comment: I tried the same solution but still not fetching keyId element name from xml to lKeyId class member name. Getting 0 value in lKeyId. Please help ...

Comment: try change `long` to `Long`

Answer (score -1):

By default, annotations doesn't work with XmlMapper in jaxb. You have to register the annotation module for this purpose as I have done in the following code block:

```
String xmlData = getMyXmlData();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JaxbAnnotationModule());        
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
MyClass myObj= objectMapper.readValue(xmlData , MyClass.class);
```

In your case, you have to overwrite the Xml to Object binding process. To do that, you can receive the the HttpRequest in your controller and then  convert the xml data to VendorData using your own java code.

Comment: In what way is that applicable to Spring MVC unmarshalling the XML data for you, into the `@RequestBody` annotated parameter? The entire point of Spring MVC doing it for you, is that you don't have to mess with things like `ObjectMapper` yourself. Why do you even think it uses `ObjectMapper`, and not JAXB itself?